# React Native App design is different in different IOS Device

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Hy everyone, I'm building a react native applications but I'm facing a issue for long time which is that the app design is different in iOS devices. The devices work iPhone 6-iphone 8 design is same and iPhone X - iPhone 13 is same. But these both groups are different in design.

Comment: It is yet I don't get your issue. What's the question exactly? Despite the scales, some features also varies.

Answer (score 0):

When you say they are different in design, do you mean their device dimensions? If so, there are some workarounds for that issue. Personally, I would recommend creating scale functions for the width and height of the device you use to develop your app. Applying the scale functions will keep your design consistent throughout different devices.

```
import {Dimensions, PixelRatio} from 'react-native';
const {width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT} = Dimensions.get('window');

// based on iphone 11s's scale
const scalew = SCREEN_WIDTH / 828;
const scaleh = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 1792;

export function normalizeh(size) {
  const newSize = size * scaleh;
  return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize));
}

export function normalizew(size) {
  const newSize = size * scalew;
  return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize));
}
```

Then when styling,

```
menuBtn: {
    width: normalizew(60),
    color: '#212529',
    marginRight: normalizew(30),
},
```